# Springのweb.xml代替クラスでServletContextの初期化関数が用意されていない

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

springで、web.xmlの代わりにWebApplicationInitnializerを使用する方法があると思いますが、
共通ヘッダを自動読み込みするための設定である

```
<jsp-config>
```

の設定方法がわかりません。

たとえばweb.xmlでは

```
<jsp-config>
    <jsp-property-group>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
        <el-ignored>false</el-ignored>
        <page-encoding>UTF-8</page-encoding>
        <scripting-invalid>false</scripting-invalid>
        <include-prelude>/WEB-INF/view/header.jsp</include-prelude>
    </jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>
```

と設定するところを、
WebApplicationInitializerでは

```
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException  {
    JspConfigDescriptor jspConfigDescriptor = new JspConfigDescriptor() {

        public Collection<TaglibDescriptor> getTaglibs() {
            return null;
        }

        public Collection<JspPropertyGroupDescriptor> getJspPropertyGroups() {
            Collection<JspPropertyGroupDescriptor> propertyGroup = new ArrayList<JspPropertyGroupDescriptor>();
            JspPropertyGroupDescriptorImpl pgDescriptor = new JspPropertyGroupDescriptorImpl();
            pgDescriptor.setUrlPatterns(Arrays.asList("*.jsp"));
            pgDescriptor.setElIgnored(Boolean.FALSE.toString());
            pgDescriptor.setPageEncoding("UTF-8");
            pgDescriptor.setIncludePreludes(Arrays.asList("/WEB-INF/view/common.jsp"));
            propertyGroup.add(pgDescriptor);
            return propertyGroup;
        }
    };
    ((ServletContextHandler.Context)servletContext).setJspConfigDescriptor(jspConfigDescriptor);
}
```

という感じになると思います(JspPropertyGroupDescriptorImplは、JspPropertyGroupDescriptorを継承したゲッターセッタークラスを実装しました。)が

```
((ServletContextHandler.Context)servletContext).setJspConfigDescriptor(jspConfigDescriptor);
```

は、jettyのservletライブラリでしか実装されていませんでした。
本番ではtomcatで動かしたいのですが、同じServletContextを継承しているだけの別クラスはtomcat8から生成してくれないのか、フレームワークレベルでエラーが発生してしまいます。

何か解決方法はあるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

結論としては、Tomcat8ではソースでJspConfigDescriptorをセットする方法はなさそうです。

TomcatにもServletContext実装クラスが`org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext`オブジェクトを保持しており、`StandardContext#setJspConfigDescriptor(JspConfigDescriptor)`メソッドがあります。このメソッドを呼び出せれば、Jetty同様にJspConfigDescriptorオブジェクトをセットできるのですが、残念ながらTomcatが生成したStandardContextオブジェクトを取得する方法がなさそうです。

`WebApplicationInitializer#onStartup(ServletContext)`で引数として渡されるServletContextは、Tomcatでは`org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContextFacade`オブジェクトというServletContext実装クラスです。さらに、ApplicationContextFacadeはApplicationContextオブジェクトを保持しており、ApplicationContextがStandardContextオブジェクトを保持している構造なのですが、たとえ`ApplicationContextFacade#getContext(String)`しても、つねにApplicationContextFacadeオブジェクトが返されるだけでStandardContextオブジェクトまでたどり着けないのです…

- JDK8
- Tomcat 8.0.24

Comment: xmlレスな設定ができるといいつつ、全ての設定ができるわけではないのですね、ありがとうございました。